# React Native using debug.keystore or my-upload-key.keystore for developement?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am just starting up with React Native and don't know the standard practices. I created a react native project and need to integrate react native firebase. React Native Firebase needs a SHA-1 for android.

Keeping in mind that I'll need to sign my app for future when I need to publish the app. I went in and followed the steps in the link to create a private signing key
https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.

It created a file my-upload-key.keystore that I placed in the android/app directory.
[image]

Here's a look at my build.gradle file preview for signing configs.

```
 signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
     release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to create a SHA-1 key for the Firebase console. But I have 2 keystores here, which one am I supposed to use?
At the moment I am in developement phase so should I just create hash for the debug.keystore and put in the Firebase console?